# Проблемы с управлением циклом в Java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
                String question = "y";

                // чтобы вводить в строки надо создать BufferedReader
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                System.out.println("Решение квадратного уравнения");

        while( question == "y" )
        {
                System.out.print("a = ");
                double a = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
                System.out.print("b = ");
                double b = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
                System.out.print("c = ");
                double c = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());

                // Math.pow() функция возведения в степень (что, в какую степень)
                double d = Math.pow(b, 2) -4*a*c;

                // если дискриминант строго меньше нуля
                if (d < 0)
                    System.out.println("Корней нет");
                else
                    if (d == 0)
                    {       
                        double x = -b/(2*a);
                        System.out.printf("Единственный корень x = %g\n", x);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double ds = Math.sqrt(d);
                        double x1 = (-b+ds)/(2*a);
                        double x2 = (-b-ds)/(2*a);

                        System.out.printf("x1 = %g\nx2 = %g\n", x1, x2);
                    }

                //------------------------------------------------------------------
                System.out.print("Продолжить? [y/n] ");
                question = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println("Вы выбрали: " + question); // для проверки
                //------------------------------------------------------------
     } //цикл

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Опяяяять. Ну не сравнивайте же строки с помощью ==, а используйте equals.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Получилось!!!

Comment: А как не со “String question = "y" ”, а с “char = ‘y’ ” ?

Comment: question = Character.parseChar(reader.readLine()); - не работает

Comment: question = Character.toString(reader.readLine().charAt(0));

Comment: Изучайте же языки систематически, а не по тьюториалам.

Comment: Gorets, спасибо! Работает!!!!

Comment: reader.readLine().charAt(0) ? А что если пользователь ничего не введёт и нажмёт Enter? Ааааааааааааааааа.... бух

Comment: question = reader.readLine();
    if (!question.equals("n")) question = "y"

ободряешь? или надо еще учесть русские, большие буквы и слово полностью? )

Comment: А что если канал вдруг оборвётся? Тогда readLine вернёт null... <br />
Аааааааааааааааааааа.... бухххх

Answer (score 0):

// Правило 1
// все переменные значение которых не меняется нужно обьявлять константами (остальные можете заменить сами)

// Правило 2
// желательно всегда использовать самое простое решение

// Правило 3
// Обьявление переменных которые используются в цыкле лучше вынести за его пределы

// Правило 4
// Код нужно разделять на логически связанные блоки, и снабжать их коментариями:

// Правило 5
// если переменная используется только один раз можно обойтись и без нее, но ее оставляют если сильно страдает читаемость кода

// Правило 6
// При сравнении константа всегда должна идти слева: (х == 5) --> (5 == x)

// Правило 7
// Нестоит выбрасывать куда-то исключения если можно обработатьт их на месте

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
   // обьявляем константы
   private static final String WELCOME_STRING = "Решение квадратного уравненияn";
   private static final String ENTER_A = "a = ";
   private static final String ENTER_B = "b = ";
   private static final String ENTER_C = "c = ";
   private static final String CONTINUE = "y";

public static void main ( final String [] args )
   {
      System.out.println ( WELCOME_STRING );

```
  // обьявляем все необходимые переменные
  final Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in );
  String code = CONTINUE;
  double a2, b, c, d, x1, x2, ds;

  // решаем уравнения до тех пор пока не надоест пользователю
  boolean oneMoreTime = true;
  while ( oneMoreTime )
  {
     // считываем необходимые параметры с командной строки:
     System.out.println ( "Введите параметры квадратного уравнения: a*x*x + b*x + c = 0" );

     System.out.print ( ENTER_A );
     a2 = scanner.nextDouble () * 2;
     // ^^ сразу умножаем на 2, 
     // так как введеное значение используется нашей програмой только удвоенным

     System.out.print ( ENTER_B );
     b = scanner.nextDouble ();

     System.out.print ( ENTER_C );
     c = scanner.nextDouble ();

     // считаем дискриминант уравнения
     d = Math.pow ( b, 2 ) - 2 * a2 * c; // Math.pow() функция возведения в степень (что, в какую степень)
     // ^^ 4 * a * c = 2 * (2 * a) * c
     // мы значение 2 * а уже подсчитали при считывании

     // проверяем дискриминант и выводим корни уравнения
     if ( 0 > d )
     {
        System.out.println ( "Корней нет" );
     }
     else
     {
        if ( 0 == d )
        {
           x1 = ( -b / a2 );

           System.out.printf ( "Один корень:\n\tx = %g\n", Double.valueOf ( x1 ) );
        }
        else
        {
           ds = Math.sqrt ( d );
           x1 = ( -b + ds ) / a2;
           x2 = ( -b - ds ) / a2;

           System.out.printf ( "Два корня:\n\tx1 = %g\n\tx2 = %g\n", Double.valueOf ( x1 ), Double.valueOf ( x2 ) );
        }
     }

     // спрашиваем юзера нужно ли продолжать
     System.out.print ( "Продолжить? [y/n] " );
     code = scanner.next ();

     oneMoreTime = code.equals ( CONTINUE );
     System.out.println ( "\tВы выбрали: '" + code + "', " + ( oneMoreTime ? "продолжаем" : "выходим" ) );
     System.out.println ();
  }
```

}
}

Comment: чертовски удобный code formatter, так и хочется пред каждой строчкой вставлять 4 пробела.

Comment: Считаю, что правило 3 снижает читабельность кода, а правило 6 и вовсе рудимент из C++, где можно случайно напечатать `=` вместо `==` и это может оставаться незамеченным некоторое время.
@jmu Обычно код копируется из IDE, где либо уже есть отступ, либо его просто добавить.

Comment: 2 @AlexeyM:  
"Обычно код копируется из IDE, где либо уже есть отступ, либо его просто добавить."

то, что я могу воспользоватся своим IDE никоим образом не влияет на удобство использования форматтера сайта

Comment: 2 @AlexeyM: 
Правило 3 - вообще это плохое правило появилось тогда когда выделение памяти для очередного обьекта было более затратной опирацией чем сейчас. снижение читабельности незначительное и в разработке должно компенсироватся правильными названиями переменных и комментами к ним

Правило 6 - каждый решает для себя стоит его придерживатся или нет. я лично хочу надеятся на свою голову чем на головы разработчиков IDE в которой я работаю

Comment: @jmu Дело не в IDE, а в спецификации языка. Java, C# и многие другие языки лишены данной проблемы, т.к. условный оператор принимает исключительно bool-выражения.

Comment: обычно, если видишь сравнение вида 5==a, то сразу почему то ожидаешь других "фокусов" - оперируют разными вещами на грани UB и подобное. И как результат, код сложно поддерживать и модифицировать.
Опытные специалисты никогда не пишут присваивание вида 5==a, даже не знаю почему. Может это как безалкогольное пиво?